# ::Before and ::After scaling even with absolute position

Tags: css

I am trying to make a hexagon box for pagination. My problem is even with absolute position on `::before` and `::after`, they continue to get affected by the content in the parent div. When the number has two symbols it works fine but with a single symbol or more than two, the `::before` and `::after` go in different directions. How can I fix this?

Here is a code example of my problem: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5X2w/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to align them with `left: 0` instead of using negative `margin-left` values.

```
.pg_current {
  position: relative;
}

.pg_current::before,
.pg_current::after {
  left: 0;
  /* remove your margin-left you previously had */
}
```

An updated example of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5X2w/2/).

Comment: You're welcome. I'd appreciate if you would except the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have stated the pseudo-elements as `position:absolute` you haven't told them where to be.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/X5X2w/4/)

**CSS**

```
.pg_pagi { 
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0; 
    text-align: center;
}
.pg_current {
     background: rgba(207, 158, 230, 0.5); 
    width: 27px; 
    height: 14px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    padding: 0px 0 3px 0; 
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.pg_current::before  { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute;
    height:0;
    width: 0px; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-bottom: 9px solid rgba(207, 158, 230, 0.5); 
    border-left: 14px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 14px solid transparent; 
    margin-top: -9px ; /* same as bottom border*/
}

.pg_current::after  { 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute;
    height:0;
    width: 0px; 
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    border-top: 9px solid rgba(207, 158, 230, 0.5);  
    border-left: 14px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 14px solid transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
    margin-bottom: 9px;  /* same as top border */
}
```